# What does SpringClassRule/SpringMethodRule actually do?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, rule

In an integration test class I met these lines of code:

```
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

When I try to navigate to the class (I use Intellij Idea) I get 'Cannot find declaration to go to'. When I try to find usage I get 'No usage found in the project'
I am familiar with concept of Rules. But still don't understand what do these two things do.
I checked this page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/
no info there.

Comment: In addition to what was said by @darren-forsythe in latest versions of Spring Boot `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` is removed and instead, you shall use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These aren't Spring Boot specific annotations, rather from the Spring Framework itself and allow use of Spring Contexts etc. without the use of the `SpringRunner`.

Javadoc, http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html

A concrete example can be found here,

http://eddumelendez.github.io/blog/2015/08/01/spring-4-2-0-springclassrule-and-springmethodrule/